# Escape XML special characters

Tags: java, regex

I want to escape special characters in XML using java. I found there is apache common-text lib which contains class i.e StringEscapeUtils but I have a different case. I want to do only if it is not escape already.

Example 1 : `"This is XML example escape special characters &amp; already "`.
For this, I don't want to do anything

Example 2: `"This is  XML example not escape special characters &"`.
For this, I want to do for &

I want to handle both cases with JAVA.

Thank you

Comment: Please clear your question. If contain `&".`. then replace to `ampersand".` ?

Comment: If the string contains `&` and is not followed by `amp;` then you want to replace the `&` in the string with `&amp;`. Is that correct?

Comment: Edited comment. Yes Abra i want to do it &amp;